# Export .jar with .txt as resource won't work

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem concerning the .jar Export. I have to include a .txt file into my jar from where I read words into a list. I used this to realize(in eclipse Run + Debug mode it works well):

```
File file = new File(Worte.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resource/wortliste.txt").getFile());
```

Now, if I export it into a JAR file, the JAR file is executable as it should, and it contains the list.txt and .java files in resource (as it should because it's homework ;-) ), but the program behaves like there was no file. I have the same problem when i use getResourceAsStream(). Does anybody know why this won't work? I don't understand that, because i did this 2 weeks ago with another code, and it worked o_O.

What i have tried:

1. deleting the Project and import into a new one
2. like 1, but into a new workspace

My System is a Windows 7 x64 PC, Eclipse Juno and JRE7.

Options I use for export:

```
[] Export generated class files and resources 
[x] export all output folders... 
[x] export java source files... 
[] export refactorings

[x] compress the contents... 
[x] add directory entries 
[x] overwrite existing files without warning


jar tvf ...
    39 Wed Jan 30 16:19:14 CET 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Jan 30 00:34:16 CET 2013 resource/
100250 Wed Jan 30 00:37:24 CET 2013 resource/wortliste.txt
     0 Wed Jan 30 00:34:16 CET 2013 wortspiel/
  1291 Wed Jan 30 01:19:14 CET 2013 wortspiel/BuchstabenKollektion.java
  2251 Sun Jan 27 16:24:42 CET 2013 wortspiel/TestBuchstabenKollektion.java
   506 Sun Jan 27 17:38:48 CET 2013 wortspiel/UI.java
  1187 Sun Jan 27 16:24:42 CET 2013 wortspiel/TestWorte.java
  2932 Wed Jan 30 01:25:00 CET 2013 wortspiel/WortspielGUI.java
  4384 Wed Jan 30 01:50:40 CET 2013 wortspiel/Worte.java
   310 Sun Jan 27 16:25:08 CET 2013 .classpath
   383 Sun Jan 27 16:22:32 CET 2013 .project
  1992 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/BuchstabenKollektion.class
  2075 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/TestBuchstabenKollektion.class
  1104 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/TestWorte.class
   942 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/UI.class
  4701 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/Worte.class
   688 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/WortspielGUI$1.class
   688 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/WortspielGUI$2.class
  3475 Wed Jan 30 16:02:12 CET 2013 wortspiel/WortspielGUI.class
```

Comment: Can you give us a listing of the jar's contents? `jar tvf jarfilename`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/760926/13075) answer may help you. It explains how `getResource`works relative to the classpath of the class in which it is called. In my experience, there is a fair chance that this is where your problem originates.

Comment: Thanks Henrik for the link, but I also tried that :/

I updated the jar content @ flup

Comment: Ther eis no `list.txt` file in jar. Only `worliste.txt`.

Comment: yeah i changed the entry i put into stackoverflow :) in my code it's still wortliste.txt ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `java.io.File` to get the contents of a file inside of a jar.  Try running the following snippet,

```
public class TestGetResource
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = TestGetResource.class.getResource("/resource/wortliste.txt");
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        File f = new File(url.getFile());
        System.out.println("File: " + f);
        System.out.println("File exists: " + f.exists());
        
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);        
            reader.read();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException notFoundEx) {
            System.out.println("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + notFoundEx.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

You should see something similar to this,

> URL: jar:file:/C:/some/path/my.jar!/resource/wortliste.txt
>
> File: file:\C:\some\path\my.jar!\resource\wortliste.txt
>
> File exists: false
>
> Caught FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\some\path\my.jar!\resource\wortliste.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Instead, use `Class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String)` to get an `InputStream` for reading the file.  If you still need to read the contents as a `File`, you could stream the contents out to a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("resource/list.txt");

File file = new File(url.getFile());

Comment: Yes I also tried that, no change. But it also should be the same as my solution, doesn't it?

Comment: Strange, It's a piece of code in my project and it works correctly.

Comment: yeah as I mentioned in my post. I had this a few weeks ago and it works correct. Don't get that...

Comment: Oh I've just seen you refer to Thread and not the Main Class. I tried, but it also fails after .jar export. In eclipse RUN/DEBUG it works :/