# java ee : how to read xml file in resources

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, deployment

I'm uploaded my java ee online in a JBOSS server using openshift.

I'm trying to open an xml file with a servlet, (servlet location: src/main/java/myservlet/myservlet.java) I can access to my servlet if I try in web naviguator/java client with html output.
My xml file is in src/main/resources/Liste.xml

I found in stackoverflow that I must use this with maven for deployment:

```
InputStream is = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/Liste.xml");
```

But in my constructor I do this to parse my xml file:

```
    File fichier = new File(nomFichier);
    document = constructeur.parse(fichier);
```

So I don't really understand how to use getResourceAsStream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will search in the local classpath, in the jar and in the directory where the class file was loaded.
If the file path starts with /, it's an absolute path otherwise the file path is relatif to the package of your class (ClassName in your case).
You can take a look at the following post: [how do you make getResourceAsStream work while debugging Java in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760756/how-do-you-make-getresourceasstream-work-while-debugging-java-in-eclipse)